# How to select a DOM element with a new attribute added by JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

With:

```
var i = 0;
jQuery("a").each(function(){
  this.nthcounter = i;
  i += 1;
});
```

I was expecting to have

```
jQuery("a[nthcounter=20]").click();
```

or

```
document.querySelector("a[nthcounter=20]").click();
```

to work, but it seems none of them does anything at all.

Comment: Setting properties like `this.href` updates the attribute because `this.href` has a setter. What you're doing is creating a regular property on the `DOMElement` object, which will do nothing to update the actual element. If you have a *good* reason for storing data on an element, use `$(this).data('nthcounter', i)`.

Comment: Thanks Blender, but it seems .data() could not get the attribute back later. I tried .data(), .attr() and .prop() (with jQuery), and only .attr() worked.

Comment: `.data()` doesn't set an attribute. You can fetch the stored value later by calling `$(this).data('nthcounter')`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var i = 0;
jQuery("a").each(function(){
  $(this).attr("nthcounter", i++);
});
```

Comment: While it's probably personal preference, I always hate seeing *increment* lines in code.   I think it's much cleaner to drop the increment line, and update the code like this:   `$(this).attr("nthcounter", i++);`    Again, it's probably preference...  but is always nicer IMO.

Comment: Well, I didn't mean to make you edit the code...  but I do like it this way better :)

Comment: Thanks pax162 that works. Personally I set a rule for myself to separate the self-inc line out of others, in order to prevent possible errors introduced by multiple self-inc in one line like `add(i++, ++i)`, which is understood differently by different compilers (I mean C/C++ compilers). I prefer ++, but did not use 'cause recently I've been dealing with a few languages, some of them does not support ++ operator.

Answer (score 1):

You're adding a property to the DOM object itself...not adding an attribute via the jQuery API.

To do what I think you're trying to do is the following:

```
var i = 0;
jQuery("a").each(function(){
  // jQuery object attr...
  $(this).attr("nthcounter", i);
  // Increment
  i++;
});
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks iamjpg! that worked!I am confused about the difference between jQuery object and the DOM representation you mentioned.. Is there a one-line statement you can provide for the difference? Otherwise a reference for this would be much appreciated.

Comment: I updated my answer as I realized I did a poor job answering it due to haste. Thanks for the question. I made a JS fiddle with comments that will hopefully help to explain what's happening a little better. http://jsfiddle.net/KmEy8/1/